# как определить координаторы на которых находиться черепаха в данный момент ли есть отдельная команда для этого?

Tags: python, turtle

```
from turtle import*
def fraktal(Theorema,step,angle,level):
    global 
    for i in range(8):
        if Theorema[i]=='+':
            right(angle)
        elif Theorema[i]=='-':
            left(angle)
        if Theorema[i]=='[':
            #записать координаты
        elif Theorema[i]==']':
            left(angle)
        elif Theorema[i]=='F':
            if level==0:
                forward(step)
            else:
                fraktal(Theorema,step/3,angle,level-1)

Theorema="F-F++F-F"
speed(0)
savecordx=0
savecordy=0
fraktal(Theorema,200,60,3)
```

Comment: `pos()` возвращает Vec2D с координатами

Comment: ясно а как туда записать эти координаты?

Comment: Куда туда записать?